# How can i implement a scanning bar animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

How do I add the green shadow effect that connected to the moving vertical line.

See the image for an example of what I am aiming for.

How can I implement this in CSS?

[image]

Here is the example that I have implemented

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.ocrloader p::before {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #18c89b;
  position: relative;
  right: 4px;
}
.ocrloader p {
  color: #18c89b;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 38%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ocrloader {
  width: 360px;
  height: 225px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 40%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ocrloader span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 0;
  width: 85%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #18c89b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #18c89b,
              0 0 1px 1px #18c89b;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(95px);
  animation: move 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.15,0.54,0.76,0.74);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.ocrloader:before,
.ocrloader:after,
.ocrloader em:after,
.ocrloader em:before {
  border-color: #18c89b;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 46px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
}
.ocrloader:before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.ocrloader:after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.ocrloader em:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.ocrloader em:after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(190px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(160px);
  }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="ocrloader">
  <p>Scanning</p>
  <em></em>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Full example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kani339/pen/abBQZop)

Comment: Div with gradient background.

Comment: it is about animation rather than the gradient itself and it is not gradient

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an idea using `box-shadow` and `clip-path`

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px;
  outline:2px solid;
  outline-offset:10px;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:20px;
  background:#18c89b;
  box-shadow:0 0 70px 20px #18c89b;
  clip-path:inset(0);
  animation:
    x 0.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate,
    y 1s   ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes x {
  to {
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    left:100%;
  }
}

@keyframes y {
   33% {
     clip-path:inset(0 0 0 -100px);    
   }
   50% {
     clip-path:inset(0 0 0 0);    
   }
   83%{
     clip-path:inset(0 -100px 0 0); 
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.ocrloader p::before {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #18c89b;
  position: relative;
  right: 4px;
}
.ocrloader p {
  color: #18c89b;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 38%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  animation: blinker 1.5s linear infinite;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ocrloader {
  width: 360px;
  height: 225px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 40%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ocrloader span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px;
  top: 0;
  width: 85%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #18c89b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #18c89b,
              0 0 1px 1px #18c89b;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(95px);
  animation: move 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.15,0.54,0.76,0.74);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.ocrloader:before,
.ocrloader:after,
.ocrloader em:after,
.ocrloader em:before {
  border-color: #18c89b;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 46px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
}
.ocrloader:before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.ocrloader:after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  border-top-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.ocrloader em:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.ocrloader em:after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
}

@keyframes move {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(190px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(160px);
  }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="ocrloader">
  <p>Scanning</p>
  <em></em>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).